# In the MySQL command line, how do you prevent new lines which occur in data values from causing a new line in the console output during a SELECT?

Tags: mysql, shell, unix, terminal, pager

When a new line occurs in a column value, when I do a select statement, the new line is formatted in my console, thereby breaking the table formatting and screwing up the column alignment.

For large tables, I use the following to prevent the formatting from breaking in my console:

```
mysql> pager less -n -i -S
mysql> SELECT * FROM table;
```

or

```
mysql> pager less -SFX
mysql> SELECT * FROM table;
```

This works fine, except for when there is a linebreak in one of the column values, which translates into a linebreak in my console, and screws up how the table displays.

Does anybody have any ideas on how to get around this?

Answer (score 2):

Use REPLACE. This drops all carriage returns and line-feeds:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(log, '\r', ''), '\n', '') FROM test;
```

http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/182689